# How to use local maven repository to create container image instead of central maven repository for google cloud

Tags: maven, docker, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, jfrog-cli

I am trying to create container image of a java application. Dependencies of the application are either on Jfrog repository or my local .m2 folder, not on central.

When I run following command to build and upload image:

```
gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/[PROJECT-ID]/image-name
```

It tries to download dependencies from central repository which are not available. I have changed the settings.xml of maven to point to Jfrog repository but still it isnt working. I believe it should first check local .m2 repository then it should go to central.

Any explanation/solution will be appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Maven to go somewhere else than Maven Central tell it to use a mirror instead.  Unfortunately this cannot be done from the command line, but needs to be done with a settings file.

Sample ~/.m2/settings.xml for pointing to a Nexus 3 instance:

```
<settings>
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>nexus1</id>
            <mirrorOf>external:*</mirrorOf>
            <url>http://nexus/repository/maven-public/</url>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
</settings>
```

Note that "external:*" says to still use local file repositories if you have artifacts in your source tree you need Maven to resolve locally.

Comment: Miror is the right solution. Do you have private dependency only in your .m2 (or somewhere else) and not published in JFrog repo?

Comment: For Nexus you can tell it to combine multiple repositories into a single view, which then can be used as a mirror URL.  I would guess Artifactory can do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Maven is searching for dependencies only at the central repo.If you want to download dependencies from elsewhere you must specify it to the pom.xml.

`<!-- url_of_project -->
<dependency>
....
</dependency>`
 Local .m2 repo is only searched first for SNAPSHOT versions.If the project is not SNAPSHOT,central repo is searched initially.

Comment: You know that `<!-- ... -->` is a comment in xml?